# How should I set up complex Factories in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

In my rails application I have three objects I would like to model for a particular Rspec test. These are Organizations, Users, and Sales Opportunities.

```
class Organization
  has_many :users
end

class User
  has_many :sales_opportunities
end
```

An Organization has to have a unique name, and for the authorisation/authentication aspects of my app to work, both users need to belong to the same Organization. For the purposes of this test I want one User to be admin and one to be non-admin.

This works successfully in other parts of my application (e.g. sign up - the first user is automatically the admin, subsequent users are not, and for viewing links etc on pages). However what I now need to do is create two users (both belong_to one organization), make one of them the admin, and then when I delete the <strike>sales_opportunity</strike> non-admin user any sales_opportunities that belonged to this non-admin user should transfer ownership to the admin (for re-allocation).

FWIW I am using associations for some of the other tests - but in this case I can't create two users associated with one organization, so I've used:

```
before(:create) do |organization|
    organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user ...admin params)
    organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user ...non_admin params)
end
```

in the factory for the organization to build 2 users who both belong to one organization and have different characteristics. This works well.

If I try to add another before(:create) to the factory to then build a sales_opportunity it fails (because the users aren't created yet I believe). After(:create) statements also fall flat. I've also tried defining the non_admin user in the tests themselves (e.g. by using a let(:non_admin) = Organization.users.last and then non_admin.sales_opportunities.create statement), but this fails to product any sales opportunities (not sure what it does).

Are there any good resources on how to build tests like this? I can write the code to solve the problems in no time - I seem to waste a huge amount of time writing the tests first. I'm sure these are not particularly DRY either looking through my factories.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you mean by "but in this case I can't create two users associated with one organization?" Looking at the information you've provided, I don't see why that wouldn't work. What's keeping you from it?

Comment: Also, this is unclear: "when I delete a sales_opportunity for the non-admin user it should transfer ownership to the admin (for re-allocation)". Ownership of what? I could only think of ownership of the `SalesOpportunity` but you just deleted that.

Comment: @awendt probably what he means is that he needs to have a factory for organization which creates admin and non admin users with sales opportunities associated with them.

Comment: Sorry - I wrote this in haste before going to another meeting. I meant when you delete the non-admin user, the sales_opportunity should pass to the admin for re-allocation to another user.

Comment: @awendt - if I add into the User factory "association :organization" this only associates one user with the organization, not many. This means that I cannot perform the tests I am looking to perform, as I only have one admin user who can't delete himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in *rspec/factories/sales_opportunities.rb*:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:name) { |n| "Sales Oppotunity - #{n}" }

  factory :sales_opportunity do
    user
    name { generate(:name) }
    # add more attributes here
  end
end
```

in *rspec/factories/users.rb*:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    organization

    sequence(:name) { |n| "Test user #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "test.user#{n}@example.com" }
    password "password"

    admin false
    # add more attributes here
  end

  factory :admin_user, parent: :user do
    admin true
  end

  factory :user_with_sales_opportunities, parent: :user, traits: [:with_sales_opportunity]

  factory :admin_user_with_sales_opportunities, parent: :admin_user, traits: [:with_sales_opportunity]

  trait :with_sales_opportunity do
    ignore do # instead of ignore use transient if you're using factory girl 4.3 or above
      sales_opportunities_count 5
    end

    after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
      sales_opportunities { FactoryGirl.create_list(:sales_opportunity, evaluator.sales_opportunities_count, user: user) }
    end
  end
end
```

in *rspec/factories/organizations.rb*:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:name) { |n| "Organization - #{n}" }

  factory :organization do
    name { generate(:name) }

    ignore do
      users_count 5
      admin_users_count 2
      sales_opportunities_count 5
    end

    after(:create) do |organization, evaluator|
      users { FactoryGirl.create_list(:user_with_sales_opportunities, evaluator.users_count, organization: organization, sales_opportunities_count: sales_opportunities_count) + FactoryGirl.create_list(:admin_user_with_sales_opportunities, evaluator.users_count, organization: organization, sales_opportunities_count: sales_opportunities_count) }
    end
    # add more attributes here
  end
end
```

Now you can:

```
let(:organization) { FactoryGirl.create(:organization, users_count: 4, admin_users_count: 3, sales_opportunities_count: 4) }
```

Comment: Thanks - I will give this a try. I have just one single Factories file with all the factories, traits and associations written within it. Is it normal practice to separate a new factory file for each new model?

Comment: Yes, please keep everything isolated. I will encourage you to create separate factories for individual models. Two reasons: 1 - Easy to read and locate code later in future by you or another developer, as developer won't have to dig into one file to see where's what. 2 - Scalability, because once your app starts growing and when minor/major changes occurs it won't be hard to update just one or two files in the context of columns/associations.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I've already noticed that relatively minor changes in my models seem to have large impacts on writing the tests. Is there any good book/resource/tutorial for learning how to write elegant factories? Mine all (eventually) work, but they are hacked together and probably horrendously slow compared to something written properly.

Comment: Factory Girl's wiki page itself is the best place for learning it: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: Thanks. I'll use your examples and that wiki to try and work out why you've selected each option.

Comment: What each option? I didn't understand. Also please select any one of the answers as the answer which will help others in future. :)

Comment: Sorry - I meant that you're using techniques there that I've not yet used in my testing. Lots of what you write looks elegant and I need to go through each line (plus the wiki) so I can understand why you have chosen to use it in this way. I haven't had time to implement your suggestion yet, but I suspect this is the right answer - and will certainly come to select it once I prove this in my code. Thanks again for your help and for the very detailed answer.

Comment: Hey, no problem. Take your time, read, learn, and experiment. That's how you grow. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. A lot of refactoring needed for the code to work (most of my tests were VERY ugly), but it's much quicker and easier to use now. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what you're trying to do, as you seem to be deleting the sales opportunity that you want to transfer?

If you think its an rspec you could instead try using *after(:build)*

Something like:

```
factory :user, class: User do
  sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@example.org" }
  password "foobar"
  # Standard user stuff etc

  trait :admin do
    after(:build) do |user|
      user.set_admin
    end
  end
end

factory :organisation, class: Organisation do
  name "Super Duper"

  after(:build) do |organization|
    organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user)
    organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user, :admin)
  end
end
```

I feel like you may have a modeling issue though.   Shouldn't your sales opportunities be standalone?

ie:

```
class SalesOpportunity
  field :name, type: String
  field :phone, type: Integer

  belongs_to :user  
end

class User
  field :name, type: String
  field :phone, type: Integer

  has_many :salesopportunities
end
```

This way you can delete a user object and persist the sale opportunity?

Comment: Why would you need `after(:build)` for an admin? Why not simply have a flag?: `trait :admin { is_admin true }`

Comment: Sorry - I made a mistake in my initial question. Users in this case set up sales_opportunities that they are pursuing. If that user is deleted from the system (e.g. if a user is fired from his organization), I want the sales_opportunities to persist (be transferred back to the admin of the Organization in order to be re-allocated to another User).